# What is an eBrochure and how would it differ from a website?

Tags: publishing

I've been asked to create a print brochure (like a traditional tri-fold) and a corresponding "ebrochure". I've never heard of an ebrochure, so in the absence of clear specifications from the client, I did a Google search for ebrochures. While this confirmed that an ebrochure is in fact a real thing, I also found a wide range of meanings and implementations.

While I will of course go back to the client for clearer specifications, I would like to have a better general understanding of the expectations of an ebrochure (if indeed there are common expectations).

1. What is an eBrochure? What is the typical content that would be included in such a product?
2. How is an eBrochure different from just a plain old website, which presumably includes the content that would appear in a brochure?

Comment: Sometimes they just want a PDF copy to put on their website. But like you said, the client would be the best resource.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field so this will just be a comment. I'm pretty sure it's just a PDF. But you don't have to make a pdf. You could make it a website that looks like a normal brochure but when you click on the images it makes them bigger or reveals their product page where you can purchase them. Something simple but useful.

Comment: In it's simplest form, you output your print file as a PDF set for screen (RGB and 72dpi) - there is a preset included with Indesign. This PDF will be small and generally works fine in browsers / mobile as it is an established file type with pre-installed support. However, you can create an eBrochure specifically for screen applications (e.g. set for HD 16:9 on a wall mounted widescreen) so ask your client how they intend to deploy it. Keep an eye on colour - if your images are CMYK, the colour will shift if you leave Indesign to convert to RGB - best you do it first in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, an eBrochure is usually a digital version of a brochure that we have developed for print. This is not always the case, more and more we are designing and creating brochures for our clients with only digital distribution in mind.

The eBrochures that we produce are typically PDF's with varying degrees of interactivity and multimedia included. That interactivity could include as little as linking a table of contents to the corresponding section of the brochure. But they can also include video and interactive items like 3D models and page transitions like page flips.

For most clients, when they request a eBrochure, they just want a digital version of the brochure you're creating, to use on their website or to email to clients. You can use the additional interactivity as an up-sell in most cases and charge more than you would for just a flat PDF copy.

Answer (score 0):

An "eBrochure" is just a generic name for any kind of electronic brochure. It's not a kind of brochure in one specific format.

It could apply to a PDF, a regular web page/online catalogue, or a brochure hosted on an online publishing platform.

Ask your client what they want or what functionality they expect from such a brochure. For example ask them if they want it to be interactive/static, viewable inside a webpage/on a browser, or if a simple PDF available for download will be suitable for customers who want to print some of the pages.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: After a little more digging on google there does seem to be an "eBrochure" genre out there:

- catalog pages taken straight from print
- delivered via custom web browser that simulates page turns

and that is just about it. Much simpler than what I originally posted...

Comment: Sorry but I find "here's what Google told me" to be a pretty poor answer.

Comment: @Scott- No doubt, but I was googling for some branded company using eBrochure as a platform for developing them, similar to ePortfolio which apparently is a big thing now. What I found was a bunch of sites that were as described. But GoofyMonkey puts it much better: a digital version of the brochure with additional interactivity.